# Adding icons to bootstrap drop down menu items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am trying to add some icons to a bootstrap dropdown menu ( see fiddle below )
as you can see the icon gets added, but it pushes the men u item to the right and that menu item is not aligned with the other items anymore.

What is the appropriate way to do this ?

[image]

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nr2mg/)

```
<div class="pull-left">
<div class="pull-right">
    <div class="btn-group">                 
            <a class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                <span>Actions</span>
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-ok"></i>Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I posted an answer but after re-reading your question, perhaps I didn't answer your question.  I don't understand - what's getting moved to the right?  Are you talking about the drop down icon?  I don't see any icons on your Fiddle.

Comment: I have added an image to show what I mean - thanks

Comment: I don't see that checkbox on your fiddle?  I wouldn't do it with the `<i>` tag.  Use a background-image like in my example and it won't reposition the text at all.  I'm manually moving the text 5 pixels over, but if you remove the `padding-left` from my answer, it won't get moved at all...

Comment: gotcha - thank you -will mark as answer

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help.  I added a small update to my answer at the bottom, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.  Unfortunately it seems that you need to use `!important` on the background-image which is usually best to try to avoid.  Note, nth-of-type is not supported in some older browsers.

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

/* First Menu Item */
.dropdown-menu li:nth-of-type(1) { 
    background-image: url("http://files.softicons.com/download/application-icons/32x32-free-design-icons-by-aha-soft/png/32/Color%20test.png") !important; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    background-position: 3px 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

/* Second Menu Item */
.dropdown-menu li:nth-of-type(2) { 
    background-image: url("http://files.softicons.com/download/application-icons/32x32-free-design-icons-by-aha-soft/png/32/Color%20test.png") !important; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    background-position: 3px 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/syVk8/

EDIT: Ok, after a little clarification it turns out you don't want the text shifting over at all.  Here is a similar example with no padding on the left and a class called 'ok' that you can apply to different menu items to add the checkbox (or whatever your icon might be):

```
li.ok { 
    background-image: url("http://files.softicons.com/download/application-icons/32x32-free-design-icons-by-aha-soft/png/32/Color%20test.png") !important; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    background-position: 3px 5px;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/syVk8/2/

Answer (score 17):

Here's how I did this in Bootstrap 3.x:

[image: Menu with icon]

**Markup:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#" class="icon"><span
         class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>User Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown-menu a.icon {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.dropdown-menu a.icon .glyphicon {
  top: 6px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

The key is that glyphicons are absolute-positioned, and even though they are "contained" inside the `<a>` in the markup, the positioning is relative to the entire menu by default.  By adding the `.icon` class to each menu anchor that contains an icon, it allows you to make the positioning relative to that anchor, and also pad the anchor text so that the icon has room to show properly.  As you can see above, any menu items that do not contain the `.icon` class or a glyphicon will display normally as a text link.

If the intention in the original question was to always have the text aligned vertically icon or not, just move the padding to `.dropdown-menu a`.