# How to add a picture to the front of the dropdown in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I want to add a square icon to each dropdown menu of a navbar in Bootstrap, and also don't like the text in the dropdown menu to be shifted due to the addition of the icon. So, when I tap my dropdown of the navbar in Bootstrap, I want it to look like the following:

```
[★] Stack Overflow
[●]   Ask Ubuntu
[∈] Think Different
```

Think of those signs wrapped with square brackets as each icon. So I don't like the text `Ask Ubuntu` to be shifted to the left just because I add an icon to the head of the dropdown list.

Is it possible to add the icon to the front of each dropdown list in the same way as I just described?

I found one similar question and answer here over Stack Overflow([Adding icons to bootstrap drop down menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554172/adding-icons-to-bootstrap-drop-down-menu-items)). However, the answer is no more valid since he uses Bootstrap 2 and hence the jsfiddle link there doesn't work any more (in fact I tried to duplicate the code there, but it didn't work), and also I don't like the idea of using `!important` to the CSS if it can be avoidable.

So anyone can help me to add the icon to the menu properly?

I use Bootstrap 3.1, and I would like it to function well at least on the latest Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. I don't mind it if it doesn't work on IE or mobile devices.

#### update

The default `text-align` of `.dropdown-menu li` is `center`, so before I add an icon, here's the default style when I tap the navbar to open the dropdown menu:

```
Stack Overflow
  Ask Ubuntu
Think Different
```

However, when I add an icon it becomes something like the follows:

```
[★] Stack Overflow
  [●] Ask Ubuntu
[∈] Think Different
```

In other words, since the default is `text-align: center`, not only the `Ask Ubuntu` text, but also `[●]` icon is positioned at the center.

However, I want to push only icons to the left, and leave the text in the center, such as:

```
[★] Stack Overflow
[●]   Ask Ubuntu
[∈] Think Different
```

instead of:

```
[★] Stack Overflow
[●] Ask Ubuntu
[∈] Think Different
```

Anyway, here's my current HTML:

```
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="/dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="/link1">
                                    <img src="image1.png">
                                    text1
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/link2">
                                    <img src="image2.png">
                                    text2
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

And CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu li
    text-align: left
```

paulalexandru, where did I say "don't need icons"? I use the term "icons" and "images" interchangeably.

Comment: post the code you have so far

Comment: What you you want exactly? The icon in the left and the text at the center? What do you mean by "you dont like the text Ask Ubuntu to be shifted" because in your example it's very shifted. You said you need icons, after that you said you don't need icons, you need images. I still don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Updated with code I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy. Use the available Glyphicons (or Font Awesome, etc.) and add them as needed.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Added star icon</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link with no icon</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, it's not glyphicons. It's images I serve that I want to put there.

Comment: If using your own images, then I would apply your images as background images with a position to the left. Then, style the rest as needed (like changing the text-align to center).